# How to check if file name contains a string with Mocha/Chai?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

I created an NPM package that contains a collection of Gulp tasks.
I added some tests using Mocha + Chai to be sure that it keeps building assets in the proper way.

One of the tests, needs to comprove that the generated compressed file exists and is not empty.

I used [`chai-fs`](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-fs/) to check if the file exists.

The issue is that the generated file is hashed so it looks like `main-07781b0850.min.css`. `07781b0850` is generated by [`gulp-rev`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev).

Here what I'm doing:

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const fs = require('chai-fs');
chai.use(fs);

describe('production', function () {
  // Styles.
  it('CSS file is minified.', function(done) {
    expect('test-website/dist/styles/main-07781b0850.min.css').to.be.a.file().and.have.contents.that.match(/\*\/(?!\n).*$/);
    done();
  });
});
```

Since I know the hash always contains 10 chars/digits, I'd like to test if the generated file match this pattern: `main-[a-z0-9]{10}.min.css`.

I did not find a way to use regex with `chai-fs` neither with [`chai-files`](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-files/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a name of the generated file then you can test if it matches the pattern with a [RegExp.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method:

```
const regex = /main-[a-z0-9]{10}.min.css/;
expect(regex.test(filename)).to.be.true;
```

In this case the test will succeed if you enter a filename as `main-07781b0850.min.css` as well as if you enter a full path like `test-website/dist/styles/main-07781b0850.min.css`.

If you want to verify the contents of the file against a pattern you can load them into a string and use the same approach.